# Forward gwt rpc request to another HTTP Servlet

Tags: gwt

How can I forward GWTRPC request to another HTTP Sevrvlet

I'm using :

RequestDispatcher rd = super.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/abc?" + sURL);
             rd.forward(super.getRequest(), super.getResponse());

but its giving me error :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response

Comment: Did you consider using RequestBuilder instead ?

Comment: This way you can call your servlet directly instead of redirecting.